# Two-coupled oscillator, problem understanding general solution

Tags: oscillators, coupled-oscillators

I want to find the general solution of this system:
[image]

First, let's assume that the system is symmetric, i.e the masses are equal. By using newtons second law for rotation on the points where the rope meets the wall I get that:

[image]

Since the system is symmetric I see that one way to solve the system is by using:

$$S(t)=\theta_1 +\theta _2$$
$$D(t)=\theta_1 -\theta_2$$

By adding the first and second equation and later subtracting. In the end I get that:

$$S(t)=Acos(w_st+\phi_1)$$
$$D(t)=Bcos(w_at+\phi_2)$$
where 
$$w_s = \sqrt{g/l}$$
$$w_a = \sqrt{g/l +2k/m}$$

This gives me:

$$\theta_1(t)=\frac{A}{2}cos(w_st+\phi_1)+\frac{B}{2}cos(w_at+\phi_2)$$
$$\theta_2(t)=\frac{A}{2}cos(w_st+\phi_1)-\frac{B}{2}cos(w_at+\phi_2)$$

I can also solve this problem by using that the general solution is a linear combination of the normal nodes. And that a normal node is where both $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ experience harmonic motion and have the same frequency. i.e when we have a normal node:

$$\theta_1(t)=C_1cos(wt+\phi_1)$$
$$\theta_2(t)=C_2cos(wt+\phi_2)$$

By inserting this into the first two equation and then solving for the determinant of the resulting matrix is zero i find that the normal frequency is:

$$w_s = \sqrt{g/l}$$
$$w_a = \sqrt{g/l +2k/m}$$

And since the solution is a linear combination of the normal nodes I get that:
$$\theta_1(t)=D_1cos(w_st+\phi_1)+E_1cos(w_at+\phi_3)$$
$$\theta_2(t)=D_2cos(w_st+\phi_2)+E_2cos(w_at+\phi_4)$$

Here is my where I reach the end of my understanding because by the solution I found by the other method:

$$D_1 = D_2$$
$$E_1 = E_2$$
$$\phi_1 = \phi_2$$
$$\phi_3 = \phi_4$$

Therefore my question is, how can I see that without using the other method that only works for a symmetric system. And also if the system is not symmetric i.e the masses are different will the 4 equalities above still hold? I suspect that since usually two differentials equation of second order only av 4 unknowns. But is this the case here?

edit 1: For the above calculation it is assumed that the angle is very small.

Comment: It is my understanding that this system is chaotic, so you can only find numerical solutions

Comment: Suggestion: Look up how to use the Lagrangian!